# Find Co-ordinates of squares edge defined by angle from center

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the co-ordinates of an edge of a square from an imaginary line from the centre of the square that goes out on a variable angle. Where that line intercepts with the edge of the square is the co-ordinates I need.

For example sake, the square is 50px X 50px the center co-ordinates are (10,10) and the angle of the line from the center is on a 45 degree angle clockwise, the end of this line should not extrude the square and I'm trying to find the x,y co-ordinates of the end of this line.

What am I using this for, I want to be able to rotate a liner gradient fill in a rect() as you would do so in photoshop. I'm also not wanting to use a library as I'm trying to "reinvent the wheel" as I find it the best way to learn for my own sake.

I'm doing this in Javascript.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you want coordinates you will need to define an origin.

Comment: I have the origin of the square, width, height and the degrees of the line from the centre co-ordinates of the square, I need the line to be the length until it hits an edge of the square, the co-ordinates of that point where it hits the edge of the square

Comment: So you will need to provide the coordinates of the square centre and also the line from which your variable angle is taken relative to (and the clockwise-anticlockwise sense). Also the pixel width of the square. As it stands you have not provided anywhere near enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: 45 degree angle relative to what? positive x-axis? y-axis? Clockwise? Anticlockwise? I think you should edit your question to provide this information if you want to get an answer.

Comment: I have added the edit, I hope that is enough detail?

Comment: An image illustrating what you're trying to achieve would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subdivide the rectangle if four sectors, then determine in which sector your line lies. One way to do that is checking the angle value with 90°, 180° and 270° using plain if statements.

Once you have the angle's sector, you have to compare the line's angle against the rectangle's diagonal angle, so you could determine the edge your line is colliding with.

[image]

Once you've determined the collision edge you get one of the collision coordinates for free (left-x, right-x, top-y or lower-y), the another coordinate can be obtained using trigonometry (the tangent relation).

You'll end up with two basic cases in every sector, one takes the opposite leg for the right triangle that forms for the collision with one of the vertical edges and the other takes the adjacent leg. Here is an example for the first sector (the upper right quadrant)

```
if (lineAngle < rectDiagAngle) {

    // For this collision you have the x coordinate, is the same as the
    // right edge x coordinate
    colX = rectX + rectW;

    // Now you need to find the y coordinate for the collision, to do that
    // you just need the opposite leg
    oppositeLegLength = Math.tan(lineAngle) * (rectW / 2);
    colY = rectCenterY - oppositeLegLength;

} else { 
    // The line collides with the top edge

    // For this collision you have the y coordinate, is the same as the
    // top edge y coordinate
    colY = rectY;

    // Now you need to find the x coordinate for the collision, to do
    // that you just need the adjacent leg
    adjacentLegLength = (rectH / 2) / Math.tan(lineAngle);
    colX = rectCenterX + adjacentLegLength;
}
```

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysLsq/14/) takes the angle, calculates the collision point and then draws a line from the rectangle center to the collision point.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do and been stuck on for hours! Thank you soo much!